# change Sql statement to Bql

Tags: c#, sql, acumatica

How can i change this SQL statement to BQL, Thank you in advance

```sql
select InventoryID ,TranDesc
from dbo.ARTran
order by case when TranDesc = 'Rounding Adjustments' then 2 else 1 end
```

Comment: here's a broad guide that might help? [To Compose a BQL Statement from an SQL Statement (Acumatica Wiki)](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=0c3be5f8-d333-4080-9180-f610b0f14757)

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
class RoundingAdjustment : PX.Data.Constant<String> { public RoundingAdjustment() : base("Rounding Adjustments") { } }

PXSelectReadonly3<ARTran,
OrderBy<Asc<Switch<Case<Where<ARTran.tranDesc, Equal<RoundingAdjustment>>, PX.Objects.CS.int2>, PX.Objects.CS.int1>>>>
```